# help with CNF conversion?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

please help me I'm stuck.
i have this question 
Q1: convert the sentence into CNF.showing each step.
Q2: prove the sentence is satisfiable or unsatisfiable using resolution.
((food ⇒ party) ∨ (drink ⇒ party)) ⇒ ((food ∧ drinks) ⇒ party)
..
my answer is..
step1: ¬((¬ food ∨ party) ∨ (¬ drinks ∨ party)) ∨ (¬(food ∧ drinks) ∨ party)
step2: ((food ∧ ¬party) ∧ (drinks ∧ ¬party)) ∨ ((¬food ∨ ¬drinks) ∨ party)

im stuck at distribution.. the rule says 
(α ∨(β ∧ γ)=(α ∨ β) ∧ (α ∨ γ)
I don't know how to do it, been searching for days please help!

Comment: You can always get the DNF of a formula right from its truth table and then negate that formula to get CNF

Comment: I can, but the teacher wants me to follow these specific steps :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking up from step 2:

$((food ∧ ¬party) ∧ (drinks ∧ ¬party)) ∨ ((¬food ∨ ¬drinks) ∨ party)$

Let's first drop some unnecessary parentheses:

$(food ∧ ¬party ∧ drinks ∧ ¬party) ∨ ¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party $

And now you indeed want to do distribution. So ∨-distribute the $¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party$ term over each of the conjuncts in $food ∧ ¬party ∧ drinks ∧ ¬party$:

$(food ∨ ¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party) ∧  (¬party ∨ ¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party) ∧ (drinks ∨ ¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party) ∧ (¬party ∨ ¬food ∨ ¬drinks ∨ party) $

Did you see how that worked?  And can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! finally i get it! Much appreciated!